# how do you deselect "all" selector if one input is deselected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a search filter that will toggle all the filters on if selected. My problem is, if you deselect all or one of the filters, the all button still stays on. How can I make it so if a filter or all the filters are deselected, the all button will automatically deslect itself.

```js
    function togglecheckboxes(master,group){
        var cbarray = document.getElementsByClassName(group);
        for(var i = 0; i < cbarray.length; i++){
            var cb = document.getElementById(cbarray[i].id);
            cb.checked = master.checked;
        }
    }
```

```css
#search_attributes {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5.5em;
  padding-left: 1em; 
}

input[type=checkbox] {
    display:none;
}

input[type=checkbox] + label {
    background: none;
    height: 50px;
    width: 72px;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    filter: grayscale(1);
    -o-filter: grayscale(1);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(1);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(1);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
}
   
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    background: none;
    height: 50px;
    width: 72px;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    filter: grayscale(0);
    -o-filter: grayscale(0);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(0);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(0);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
    -o-transition:.1s;
    -ms-transition:.1s;
    -moz-transition:.1s;
    -webkit-transition:.1s;
}
```

```html
<div id="search_attributes">
            <section>
                <input type="checkbox" id="cb1_1" class="cbgroup1" name="cbg1[]" value="1">
                <label for="cb1_1">
                    <img src="images/oneshot_selector.png" />
                </label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="cb1_2" class="cbgroup1" name="cbg1[]" value="2">
                <label for="cb1_2">
                    <img src="images/loop_selector.png" />
                </label>
            </section>
            <section>
                <input type="checkbox" id="cbgroup1_master" onchange="togglecheckboxes(this,'cbgroup1')">
                <label class="all" for="cbgroup1_master">
                    <img src="images/all_selector.png" />
                </label>
            </section>
            <section>
                <input type="checkbox" id="cb1_3" class="cbgroup1" name="cbg1[]" value="3">
                <label for="cb1_3">
                    <img src="images/sfx_selector.png" />
                </label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="cb1_4" class="cbgroup1" name="cbg1[]" value="4">
                <label for="cb1_4">
                    <img src="images/music_selector.png" />
                </label>
            </section>
        </div>
```

Comment: You'll have the same problem as well if you manually check each of the boxes; the button won't be "on". What you need to do is listen for the click event on each checkbox, that checks whether or not *all* the checkboxes are checked and the update the status of your button accordingly.

Comment: You would have to have an event on the other select buttons that checks the checked state. If one is found unchecked, then deselect the "all" checkbox. Otherwise check it/leave it checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple! Your goal is to change the master based on the following...

- if a checkbox is unchecked, make sure the master is unchecked too
- otherwise, make sure that all checkboxes are checked before the master is checked

**Translated to jQuery:**

```
$(".cbgroup1").on("change", function () {

    var $checkbox = $(this),
        $checkboxes = $("#search_attributes").find(".cbgroup1"),
        $master = $("#cbgroup1_master");

    if (!$checkbox.is(":checked")) {
        $master.prop("checked", false);

    } else {
        if ($checkboxes.length === $checkboxes.filter(":checked").length) {
            $master.prop("checked", true);
        }
    }

});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/6rc9p0qm/

Done!

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see any jquery here, but since you have the tag, I shall use it!

First, we can slightly alter the html:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cbgroup1_master" data-group="cbgroup1">
```

Then we can move the binding into the javascript (btw, i'm not proposing you put your function definition in the ready function, but just keeping the code together):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function togglecheckboxes() {
        var $this = $(this);

        $('.'+ $this.data('group')).prop('checked', $this.is(':checked'));
    }

    $('#cbgroup1_master').on('change', togglecheckboxes);
});
```

That will set the checked status of the associated group to match the parent.  Now for the children to undo the parent.  We can slightly change their structure to help too:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1_1" class="cbgroup" name="cbg1[]" value="1" data-group="1">
```

Then in the ready function we can bind to them with the shared class.

```
$('.cbgroup').on('change', function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    if (!$this.is(':checked')) {
        $('#cbgroup'+ $this.data('group') +'_master').prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

This, in the case that a cbgroup changes, it will change its parent to unchecked (if it was originally checked), based on the data-group to know which parent to go to.

Since you did not have any jquery in your example, just to make sure you are informed, I'll include the following.  If this is a *"duh"* to you, I'm sorry, :).

With jquery, in a selector (ex. `$('selector')` ), using `$('.string')` will find all elements where `'string'` is a class of theirs.  Using `$('#string')` will find the element where `'string'` is the `id`.